# error: legacy-install-failure when installing apex

Tags: pip, pytorch, apex, virtual-environment

I followed the method(https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex#quick-start) to install apex with CUDA and C++ extensions(Linux), but I got the error in the picture.
Local environment version: pytorch:1.13.1+cuda:11.7

Command:

```
git clone github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

Error:

```
Using pip 23.0.1 from /home/kang/miniconda3/envs/atlop/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option. Consider using --config-settings for more flexibility.
DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
Processing /hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
      from packaging.version import parse, Version
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  See above for output.
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/kang/miniconda3/envs/atlop/bin/python -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )`enter code here`
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"

  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3awzykxh
  cwd: /hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex/
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details
```

Please help me to explain the cause of the error and how to solve it (could it be a version problem, he stressed that it is a packbag problem, could it be a problem with apex source code?)

Comment: Hi @kobe Bryant! Several things: 1. Please post the commands that lead you to the error. 2. Post the complete error output. 3. Post it as text and not as a picture. :)

Comment: commands:
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./

Comment: The error is too long, I added the full error picture to the question, thanks

Comment: If the error is too long, just put what is necessary. Never post images of code or output. Could you please update your question?

Comment: Already uploaded thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pip install packaging` before? And then, rerun your command

Answer (score 1):

The following error is being printed:

```
Processing /hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/hdd2/code_zy/ATLOP/apex/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
      from packaging.version import parse, Version
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

It means that the `pip install` command needs the package packaging to be already installed to correctly install apex.

Install the missing package before installing apex:

```bash
pip install packaging
# Then, your commands
git clone github.com/NVIDIA/apex
cd apex
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

---

The link to the Pypi page of the packaging package: https://pypi.org/project/packaging/.